# Storing matrices in a relational database

Tags: sql, database-design, matrix-storage

I am working on a project for a client and going through the initial database design. The project will be a simple web app for tracking processes and their outcomes within a matrix diagram, I am looking for a good way to store these in relational tables.

Right now I am thinking I have a general table for Routines which the x and y coords will map too and maybe off from that a lookup table containing the ID of coordinates in which a "hit" is recorded. Anyone have any better ways of doing this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is just the beginning of the project so I have limited detail as of yet, but my main reasoning behind multiple tables is because the matrices will be completely dynamic in size and generic so that each one may be different and they will be tied to a user

I also forgot to mention that order of the x/y values are important, which further supported my reasoning behind having multiple tables for x y and values, from this I strongly assume that needing to know each individual cell is important

EXAMPLE:

The basic example (albeit abstract) of this lies in the process regarding a restaurant. The actions being stuff along the lines of sit down, order food, look over menu, order drinks, eat, pay, etc. the outcomes being order taken, drinks delivered, food delivered, change given. While seemingly simple it becomes complex when taken into consideration things happen differently with each occurrence, also in the case of take out or buffets. the order of the actions and outcomes becomes integral in seeing the differences between the situations

Comment: How will you query the data? Will there be any aggregated queries? Do the results need sorting... on what properties? What properties of a matrix will you look for when searching for appropriate records, i.e. what will the WHERE clause be? Will your queries always be fetching entire matrices or might you just want a part of a matrix?

Comment: Please provide us with more details on what kind of matrix. Typical size, dimension fixed or not, what kind of elements are stored in the matrix. Some examples may be helpful, too.

Comment: the data will be queried based on the user who is using the application and all tied back up to the routine's ID

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you mean as it's really not too clear what your specific needs are here.  At this point only a general answer is possible.

Comment: fyi, to store a matrix that is 50,000 x 50,000 in size but with 4 data points you would set it up one way. to store a matrix that is 100 x 100 in size but with a million data points you would set up the tables in a completely different way.  you may need to support "any" matrix, but you need to get a rough idea of what is typical and bias your design to fix that, yet still be workable for the other situation.

Comment: Limited detail or not, what you have told us is all disconnected and doesn't make a lot of sense: you say its for "tracking processes and their outcomes within a matrix diagram." What does that mean? Why would you need a matric for that?  What kinds of things would go into the matrix? An example would help loads here.  You say "a general table for Routines which the x and y coords will map too", huh?  What is the connection between this and your first statement?  Are processes and routines supposed to be the same thing? What are X and Y? Do they have any thing to do with your rows and columns?

Comment: Then you say "off from that a lookup table containing the ID of coordinates in which a 'hit' is recorded", again, what connection does this have to the first two statements?  What is a "hit" and why do you need it recorded.  What are the "coordinates" of a hit?  Is that your X and Y, or your row & column numbers? Or are they all the same thing?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that you may have misused the term matrix, when in fact you want a log (sequential list of actions and outcomes).

Comment: Hmm, having looked at your example, I suspect that what you really want isn't Matrices encoded as tables, but actual SQL Tables.  They're actually quite adept at doing all of these things. And usually they're batter at it than a Matrix could ever hope to be.

Comment: A Log-table may be just the ticket too.

Comment: I suppose you are right, they simple will be displayed in a matrix format when the user creates/updates/views them

Comment: @Jimmy: Please change the title of your question, it is totally misleading, everyone else here uses the word 'matrix' in a completely different way than you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are lots of way to do this, we would need a lot more information to be more specific about what would be best for you.  However, here are the two SOP ways:

Either a separate table for each matrix:

```
CREATE TABLE YourMatrixName(
    RowNo smallint NOT NULL,
    ColNo smallint NOT NULL,
    CellValue varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Matrices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([RowNo] ASC, [ColNo] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourMatrixName ON dbo.YourMatrixName
    (ColNo, RowNo); 
GO
```

Or, all of the matrices in one table:

```
CREATE TABLE Matrices(
    MatrixName varchar(24) NOT NULL,
    RowNo smallint NOT NULL,
    ColNo smallint NOT NULL,
    CellValue varchar(50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Matrices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([MatrixName] ASC, [RowNo] ASC, [ColNo] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Matrices ON dbo.Matrices
    (ColNo, RowNo); 
GO
```

---

These are standard normal form, virtually all other ways of doing it are not well normalized.  Some advantages of these approaches:

1. You do not have to fill in every cell, only the ones you are using. Or have a default value (0 or "") and skip those.
2. This is easily the most flexible approach, even in the "all in one" model, there is no need to restrict them to the same size in any way, and it is very easy to resize them.
3. You can easily query the ***contents*** of the matrix, something that is increasingly difficult in more compact storage methods.
4. "Hit"s or any other aspect of the matrix cells are easy to implement as additional fields in the rows.  Make them Null-able if you're worried about the additional space, and index them if you want to query/report on these attributes separately.  Its also just as easy to retrofit features like this with this model also.

The primary disadvantage is that there is typically a high space to data overhead.  Many assume that there is also high overhead to Insert or retrieve new matrices but in fact there are several documented techniques that can make it quite fast.

Answer (score 8):

Video memory, a very simple 2D matrix is stored as follows:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
```

in ram sequentially like an array as

`A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L`

element x,y can be found at array offset

```
[y*width+x]
```

for instance, x=2,y=2 (zero-based) refers to element K.

`[y*width+x]=[2*4+2]=10.` array element 10 (again zero-based) = K, so you're good.

Storing in a comma-delimited list will let you put a matrix of any size in an nvarchar field. This **assumes that you don't need to query individual cells in SQL**, but just grab the matrix as a whole and process it client-side.

Your table may look like this:

```
tbl_matrices
----
id
user_id
matrix nvarchar(max)
```

Comment: BUt only do this if you areSURE that you will not need to query individual cells

Comment: This is a very un-normalized technique.  It appears very flexible at first, but in fact, virtually anything that you might want to do with it in SQL down the road becomes more and more difficult to implement.

Comment: ... thus the phrase, "assumes you don't need to query individual cells in SQL." If the matrices in question need to be manipulated mathematically, etc by a client, and don't need to be queryable in the strictest since on the SQL side, this approach works well. If the need should arise to normalize each matrix, this can be accomplished very easily with a throw-away client app. Also, a CLR UDF or sproc can be used to separate this data and perform whatever is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Is your matrix dense of sparse? If it's sparse, it may be better for each entry to just store a list of hit's, rather than have a full 2D table that is mostly 0's.

Comment: the matrices will be dynamic and editable so flexibility is a must

Answer (score 3):

Rather than two tables, I would just use one table: (x, y, outcome). Beyond that it's hard to give any more advice with the limited information given.

Comment: this could be possible but I feel it would be easier to code with multiple tables representing one thing, and being able to easily tie each element to have a human readable representation

Comment: I'm not sure how having a random ID number makes things more readable