# How to print table when only coordinates are available

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I had a table in mysql, but at some point it grew too much and I needed to change it to coordinates only (it was half empty anyway).

Imagine following:

----X --Y --Z --A-
A --1 --0 --0 --0
B --0 --1 --0 --0
D --0 --1 --1 --0
X --0 --0 --0 --1

Then I changed it just to table of coordinates for 1s (true):
main - sub
A -- X
B -- Y
D -- Y
D -- Z
X -- A
In reality table is around 300x500.

Now, the coordinates can be added freely and they can appear in columns and rows, so I do not have reference list. Can anyone suggest how to print a table out of it? I am thinking already for a longer while how to approach this.

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing the order of the rows in your table? A, B, D, and X being separate rows means nothing if you don't have a way to determine which order the actual table rows will go in from your query.

Comment: maybe interesting? [Storing matrices in a relational database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2142719/3184785).

Comment: @ShamSUP order is random as "coordinates" can change, I can remove something, add, in printing it can be alphabeting, can be as fetched, not important. my general idea for now: fetch amount of unique in row A, fetch amount of unique in row B. Create matrix unique_A x unique_B, fill up with zeros and start updating "1" as per coordiantes array[valueA][valueB]... later print as it goes. Does anyone have anything better?